# how to update a database entry and then get it without chance of another thread changing in between

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update 1 `row` of a mysql database and then get its content.  without a chance of 2 threads updating at the same `row`

```
UPDATE models 
    SET `modelInfoProcessing` = (@cur_value := `id`)*0 + 1 
    WHERE (`modelInfoProcessing` = -1 OR `modelInfoProcessing` = 0) AND `modelInfoAge`<1 
    LIMIT 1;
SELECT @cur_value;
```

works.  It updates `modelInfoProcessing` to 1 so no other thread will update and then returns the id.  However when I try

```
UPDATE models 
    SET `modelInfoProcessing` = (@cur_value := `id`)*0 + 1 
    WHERE (`modelInfoProcessing` = -1 OR `modelInfoProcessing` = 0) AND `modelInfoAge`<1 
    LIMIT 1; 
SELECT `id`,`shop`,`file`,`modelInfo`,`modelInfoAge` 
    FROM models 
    WHERE `id`=@cur_value 
    LIMIT 1;
```

to get more then just the id back it works from phpmyadmin but not from php mysqli.  Any idea what the best way to do this is?  I can't just lock the entire `row` or table as I need the rest of the `row` to be editable by different threads just need to make sure I have a way of knowing if things are trying to access to handle collisions programmatically.

My PHP Code:

```
$query='UPDATE models SET `modelInfoProcessing` = (@cur_value := `id`)*0 + 1 WHERE (`modelInfoProcessing` = ? OR `modelInfoProcessing` = 0) AND `modelInfoAge`<' . MODEL_INFO_AGE . ' LIMIT 1; SELECT `id`,`shop`,`file`,`modelInfo`,`modelInfoAge` FROM models WHERE `id`=@cur_value LIMIT 1;';
$stmtNextTask = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmtNextTask->prepare($query);
$stmtNextTask->bind_param('i',$minLevel);
$stmtNextTask->bind_result($currentTask,$shop,$file,$modelInfo,$modelInfoAge);

echo $stmtNextTask->error;die();
```

returns

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `id`,`shop`,`file`,`modelInfo`,`modelInfoAge` FROM models WHERE `id`=@cur' at line 1
```

but as I said it does run in php my admin

Comment: are you using php multi query ? mysqli multiple statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php), or make a stored proc out of it

Comment: i assume you are on innodb, but do tell us

Comment: not sure what either of those are.  I added my code to the question.

Comment: Does your mysql support START TRANSACTION and COMMIT/ROLLBACK?  If so, they would work.  There may be a more compact way -- there is in other SQLs.  But if not, transactions are your answer.

Comment: I have been googling transactions since your comment and can not find any good examples using transactions with prepared statements.  I do think I have figured out how to use though so will try this out when kids have there nap and post my findings.

Comment: Turns out it works perfectly if you split into 2 separate prepared statements.